# issue logging arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist

I am trying to log the contents of an arraylist. The arraylist contains a custom object with 4 parameters. When I execute the following code I get the following log. what i want is a string of [name,class,thirty,ninety],[name,class,thirty,ninety], etc

Custom Object Class:

```
public class Data {
        String NAME;
        String CLASS;
        String THIRTY;//this is the thirty day supply
        String NINETY;//this is the ninety day supply

    public Data(){
        super();
    }
    public Data(String NAME, String CLASS, String THIRTY, String NINETY){
        super();
        this.NAME = NAME;
        this.CLASS = CLASS;
        this.THIRTY = THIRTY;
        this.NINETY = NINETY;
    }

    }
```

Activity:

```
ArrayList<Data> array = new ArrayList<Data>();

Cursor c = mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(Constants.K_Table, null, Constants.Name +"=?", new String[] {SEARCH}, null, null, null);

            startManagingCursor(c);
            if (c.moveToFirst()){

            NAME = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.Name));
            CLASS = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.Class));
            THIRTY = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.Month));
            NINETY = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.Three_Month));

            array.add(new DrugData(NAME, CLASS, THIRTY, NINETY));
            Log.d(TAG, "array contains: "+ array.toArray().toString());
            }while(c.moveToNext());
```

Log:

```
01-28 22:31:44.742: D/Activity(23656): the array contains: [com.Data@40552050]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your objective to print String of object you have to do two things in your code.
 1) Override `toString` method.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Data [NAME=" + NAME + ", CLASS=" + CLASS + ", THIRTY=" + THIRTY
            + ", NINETY=" + NINETY + "]";
}
```

2) `ArrayList<Data> array` is collection of Data objects. You have to specify which object you want to print. You can do that in two ways.

```
    int index = 0;// Index of object in the ArrayList
    Log.i("Data",array.get(index).toString());//Preferred Method to get object
    Log.i("Data",array.toArray()[index].toString());
```

You can loop through your array to print all Data objects like this

```
    for (Data data : array) {
        Log.i("Data",data.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `toString()` method to your `Data` class.

like this

```
public String toString() {
    return NAME + " " + CLASS + " " THIRTY + " " + NINETY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `array.toArray().toString()` calls the `Object` class' `toString` method, which prints a hash of the location in memory where the array is located.

I think what you want is something like this:

```
Log.d(TAG, "added "+ NAME + ":" + CLASS + ":" + THIRTY + ":" + NINETY + " to array";
```